# How to select an ID that has a specific number in it from 10 or more ID's

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to get a random ID from a bunch of ID's

```
<table>
  <tr id="big1>1</tr>
  <tr id="big2>2</tr>
  <tr id="big3>3</tr>
  <tr id="big4>4</tr>
</table>
```

I want to do like a random number and then get that *id* ,but I don't know how to write it

```
var x=3;
document.getElementById('big[x]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form the *id* with string contention with `+`:

```js
var x = 3;
console.log(document.getElementById('big'+x));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="big1">1</tr>
  <tr id="big2">2</tr>
  <tr id="big3">3</tr>
  <tr id="big4">4</tr>
</table>
```

You can also try with [`Template Literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which allows *embedded expressions*:

```js
var x = 3;
console.log(document.getElementById(`big${x}`));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="big1">1</tr>
  <tr id="big2">2</tr>
  <tr id="big3">3</tr>
  <tr id="big4">4</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with concatination **+**:

```js
var x=3;
const dom = document.getElementById('big'+x);

console.log(dom);
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="big1">1</tr>
<tr id="big2">2</tr>
<tr id="big3">3</tr>
<tr id="big4">4</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have it, but for the sake of reusability, wrap it in a function.

```
const getBigEl = n => document.getElementById(`big${n}`);

getBigEl(4); // <tr id="big4">4</tr>
getBigEl(2) // <tr id="big2">2</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numero_random = Math.floor(Math.random() * document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows.length) + 1;
console.log(numero_random);
var x = document.getElementById('big' + numero_random);
console.log(x);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="big1">1</tr>
  <tr id="big2">2</tr>
  <tr id="big3">3</tr>
  <tr id="big4">4</tr>
</table>
```